# Import javax.enterprise.context in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I´m working on a Java EE Maven project in Eclipse Neon. I wanted to `import javax.enterprise.context` but it cannot be resolved. According to oracle, the `javax.enterprise.context` was introduced in Java EE 6, so i wanted to add the library (Project properties -> Java build path -> Libraries -> Add Library). The problem is, there is no Java EE 6 (or Java EE 7) library to chose, only the Java EE 5 library, see screenshot.

[image]

After doing some research, I found a Java EE 6 folder containing the specific jars in the same folder where the Java EE 5 folder is placed (see screenshot 2)

[image]

Do you guys know why it´s not possible to add the Java EE 6 library to my project although there is a Java EE 6 folder?

For information: I´m using Jboss Tools 4.4.1  and a Wildfly 10.1 server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should never use the Eclipse "Add Library..." feature when you are working with Maven projects.

Instead, just add the following dependency to your pom.xml and reimport the project into eclipse as a "Maven Project"

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Eclipse Maven support will sort the libraries out on your behalf.

Comment: With emphasis on the scope:provided, you really do not want this dependency to end up in your war/ear.